# How to show Manual record status popup modal after submitted data succesffully? and if not submiited then show error popup modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

[image: how to close add popup after submitting data]

how to close Add country popup after submitting the form? I am new in react js and using bootstrap 5 modal component for popup... i want to show that if data is submiitted successfully then showing success Record status popup otherwise it will showing an error Record status popup

country.js component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../../components/masters/masters.common.css';
import  AddCountry from './addCountry'
import Tabs from '../CommonMasters/tabs';

class Country extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.get = this.get.bind(this);
    this.newRecord = this.newRecord.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      currentIndex: -1,
      id: null,
      countrycode: "",
      name: "",
      region: "",
      isClosePopup : false
    };
  }

  refreshData() {
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: 1,
    });
  }

  get() {
    this.setState({ currentIndex: 1 });
  }

  newRecord() {
    this.setState({
      id: null,
      countrycode: "",
      name: "",
      isClosePopup: false
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="masterContainer">
          <h4 className="pb-2 md-2 ">Countries</h4>
          <div className=" d-flex row">
            <div className="col-8">
              <input className="form-control mb-4" id="tableSearch" type="text"
                placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-4">
              <div className='d-grid gap-2 d-md-block mb-4'>
                <button className="btn btn-primary me-3" type="button">Search</button>
                <button className="btn btn-primary " type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" onClick={this.newRecord}>Add + </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* modal  */}
          <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          { !this.state.isClosePopup &&
             <AddCountry show={false} />
          }
          </div>
          <Tabs type="country"/>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Country;
```

addCountry.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getAuthorizedList } from '../../redux/master/Country/actions'
import { createRecord } from "../../redux/master/Country/actions";
import AddRecordSuccess from '../CommonMasters/addRecordSuccess';
import AddRecordFail from '../CommonMasters/addRecordFail';

class AddCountry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.saveRecord = this.saveRecord.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      id: null,
      countrycode: "",
      name: "",
      isSubmit: false
    };
  }

  onChangeCountryCode = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      countrycode: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onChangeCountryName = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.props.getAuthorizedList()
  }

  saveRecord() {
    const data = {
      countrycode: this.state.countrycode,
      name: this.state.name,
    }
    this.props
      .createRecord(data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("addedresponsee....", response)
        this.setState(() => ({
          countrycode: data.countrycode,
          name: data.name,
          isSubmit: true,
        }));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("errror", err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div show={true} className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Country</h5>
              <button type="button" className="btn-close bg-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body bg-light">
              <form>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="mb-3 col-6">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Country Code</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="countrycode"
                      placeholder="Country Code" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                      onChange={this.onChangeCountryCode}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mb-3 col-6">
                    <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">Country Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name"
                      placeholder="Country Name" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                      onChange={this.onChangeCountryName}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer bg-light">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.saveRecord} data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#recordModal">
                Save
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        {/* record status modal */}
        { this.state.isSubmit === true ?
          <AddRecordSuccess/> : <AddRecordFail/>
        }
      </>

    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, { createRecord, getAuthorizedList })(AddCountry);
```

SuccessPopup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AddRecordSuccess extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {/* record status modal */}
                <div className="modal fade" id="recordModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
                                <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Record Status</h5>
                                <button type="button" className="btn-close bg-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body bg-light">
                                Record add successfully
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default AddRecordSuccess;
```

ErrorPopup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AddRecordFail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {/* record status modal */}
                <div className="modal fade" id="recordModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header bg-dark text-white">
                                <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Record Status</h5>
                                <button type="button" className="btn-close bg-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body bg-light">
                                Record failed to add
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default AddRecordFail;
```

Comment: You should mapState (status of AddRecord) to the `Popup` you want to show. I think you just need to use one Popup only (EX: Adding class .success and .failed to Modal for styling)

Comment: Sorry @HaiTien i don't understand what you want to say? can u pls repeat again by showing some related examples? or show me where i  should to changes in my code..